# Select objects that contain specific child elements

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following classes.

```
public class Bin
{
    public int BinId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Component> Components { get; set; }
}

public class Component 
{
    public int ComponentId { get; set; }
    public string ComponentName { get; set; }
}
```

Using LINQ how do I find all `Bin` objects that contain specific set of components, say components with IDs 1, 2, 3?

**Edit**

Just to clarify all IDs must be present in a `Bin`. Also I have a collection that contains IDs to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var bins = new List<Bin>();
var ids = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };

// go through each bin and make sure it has all the items in ids
bins.Where(x => ids.All(id => x.Components.Select(c => 
    c.ComponentId).Contains(id)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
bins.Where(b => b.Components.Any( c => new[]{1,2,3}.Contains(c.ComponentId) )
```

If you need all:

```
bins.Where(b => b.Components.All( c => new[]{1,2,3}.Any( i => i == c.ComponentId) ))
```

Or if you need that some items in the list has this items:

```
bins.Where(b => new[]{1,2,3}.All(i => b.Components.Any(c => i == c.ComponentId) ))
```

You can combine all/any/contains in sub query as you want

Comment: This will match all bins than contains at least one component with id 1,2, or three

Comment: Thank you. How would I find bins containing all of the components.

Comment: I think the last one is it.

Comment: Add more details next time, please

Answer (score 1):

```
IEnumerable<int> test = ...;
bins.Where(x => !test.Except(x.Components.Select(c => c.ComponentId)).Any());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bins.Where(x => x.Components.Any(y  => y.ComponentId ==1 || y.ComponentId == 2 || y.ComponentId == 3))
```

Try this one.

If you have list of integers then you can modify last conditions like below.

```
y => list.Any(z => y.ComponentId == z)
```

Or something like this.

```
y => list.Contains(y.ComponentId)
```

These conditions are to contain at least one component id. If you want to contain all component ids you can use `All` method instead of `Any`